# how to pass array of values to a new column of a dataframe

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame to which I want to add a column with the values which are present in an array. I want each value in the array to be placed in the column as each row.
For Example:

```
val partitionName= "processingdatadate";
val partitionValue= "20170528,20170529,20170530";
var parts: Array[String] = partitionValue.split(",")
var partValues = parts.toSeq
```

I have a data frame 'loadParqDf' so to this I want to add a column with name 'processingdatadate'

```
loadParqDF = loadParqDF.withcolumn(partitionName, lit(partValues))
```

This method is not working because the output is not expected :

```
processingdatadate
----------------------------
[20170528,20170529,20170530]
```

I am expecting output as:

```
processingdatadate
------------------
20170528
20170529
20170530
```

Comment: What is the output that you want?

Comment: hi philantrovert I have mentioned required output in my question. Please help me out. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: where are your other columns of your output dataframe? do they matter or not?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan they dont matter . I just need the code which can fetch me the values in an array in each row.

Comment: you can use `explode` in that case. you already have an array in that column. so using explode on that column would have each items in the array to be separate on each rows. :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I dint understand your answer can u please elaborate it . Please?

Comment: this question is already marked duplicate. didn't you find answer in the link ?

Comment: try `loadParqDF.withcolumn(partitionName, explode(col(partitionName))).show`. for this you would need `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`